# NullPointerException when calling a database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, list, nullpointerexception

As the title says I get a NullPointerException when I try to get a list from a database. Here is the code:

```
public List<String> getAllRockBands() {
     List<String> bandList = new ArrayList<String>();

     String selection = BAND_GENRE + "=1";

     SQLiteDatabase db = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor cursor = db.query(BANDDATABASE_TABLE,new String[]{BAND_NAME}, selection, null, null, null, BAND_NAME);

     int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(BAND_NAME);

     if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
          String bandName = cursor.getString(index);
             bandList.add(bandName);
         } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     }

     return bandList;
 }
```

`

```
public class RockAllFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

    private BandDatabaseAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
    private List<String> bandList = mySQLiteAdapter.getAllRockBands();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSherlockActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, android.R.id.text1, bandList));
    }
}
```

I am still learning to code in this environment, so I guess this is just some beginner mistake?

**EDIT:** (it's a bit much but you asked)

```
public class BandDatabaseAdapter {

 private static final String TAG = "BandDatabase";

 private static final String BANDDATABASE_NAME = "BAND_DATABASE";
 private static final String BANDDATABASE_TABLE = "BAND_TABLE";
 private static final int BANDDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 public static final String BAND_NAME = "name";
 public static final String BAND_GENRE = "genre";
 public static final String BAND_POPULAR = "popular";
 public static final String BAND_SELECTED = "selected";

 private static final String BANDDATABASE_CREATE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + BANDDATABASE_TABLE
 + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + BAND_NAME
 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + BAND_GENRE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + BAND_POPULAR
 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + BAND_SELECTED + " TEXT NOT NULL)";

 private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
 private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
 private final Context context;

 public BandDatabaseAdapter(Context c) {
       sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(c, BANDDATABASE_NAME, null, BANDDATABASE_VERSION);
       context = c;
    }

 public BandDatabaseAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
  sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
  return this; 
 }

 public BandDatabaseAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
  sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  return this; 
 }

 public void close(){
  sqLiteHelper.close();
 }

 public void updateBand(String name, String selected) {
     ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
     contentValues.put(BAND_SELECTED, selected);
     sqLiteDatabase.update(BANDDATABASE_TABLE, contentValues, "BAND_NAME=" + name, null);
     close();
 }

 public List<String> getAllRockBands() {
     List<String> bandList = new ArrayList<String>();

     String selection = BAND_GENRE + "=1";

     SQLiteDatabase db = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor cursor = db.query(BANDDATABASE_TABLE,new String[]{BAND_NAME}, selection, null, null, null, BAND_NAME);

     if(cursor!=null)
     {
     int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(BAND_NAME);

     if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
          String bandName = cursor.getString(index);
             bandList.add(bandName);
         } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     }
     }
     return bandList;
 }

 public List<String> getMyList() {
     List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

     String selection = BAND_SELECTED + "=1";

     SQLiteDatabase db = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor cursor = db.query(BANDDATABASE_TABLE,new String[]{BAND_NAME}, selection, null, null, null, BAND_NAME);

     int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(BAND_NAME);

     if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
          String bandName = cursor.getString(index);
             myList.add(bandName);
         } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     }

     return myList;
 }

 public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
    CursorFactory factory, int version) {
   super(context, name, factory, version);
  }

  private boolean doesDatabaseExist(Context context, String dbName) {
        File dbFile=context.getDatabasePath(dbName);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if(!(doesDatabaseExist(context,BANDDATABASE_NAME)))
   {
      db.execSQL(BANDDATABASE_CREATE);
      loadDatabase();
   }
  }

  /**
   * Starts a thread to load the database table with bands
   */
  private void loadDatabase() {
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              try {
                  loadBands();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  throw new RuntimeException(e);
              }
          }
      }).start();
  }

  //loads a database from a txt file
  private void loadBands() throws IOException {
      Log.d(TAG, "Loading bands...");
      final Resources resources = context.getResources();
      InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.bands);
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

      try {
          String line;
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, "^");
              if (strings.length < 4) continue;
              long id = addBand(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim(), strings[2].trim());
              if (id < 0) {
                  Log.e(TAG, "unable to add band: " + strings[0].trim());
              }
          }
      } finally {
          reader.close();
      }
      Log.d(TAG, "DONE loading words.");
  }

  public long addBand(String name, String genre, String popular) {
      ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
      initialValues.put(BAND_NAME, name);
      initialValues.put(BAND_GENRE, genre);
      initialValues.put(BAND_POPULAR, popular);
      initialValues.put(BAND_SELECTED, "0");

      return sqLiteDatabase.insert(BANDDATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + BANDDATABASE_TABLE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
  }

 }

}
```

Additional info: Some people have told me to use SimpleCursorAdapter, but it says it is deprecated. Also, note that my list has over 150k rows, tho I will greatly lessen that if the need arises. :)

Comment: can you pls post the Logcat so we can assist you?

Comment: post BandDatabaseAdapter class code also

Comment: seems it is causing an error in this row:  

`private List<String> bandList = mySQLiteAdapter.getAllRockBands();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't created SqliteHelper Class object before calling `getAllRockBands()`  Please check that once or else post your SqliteHelper Class Constructor code

Changing your code here check it.

```
public class RockAllFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

    private BandDatabaseAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
    private List<String> bandList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mySQLiteAdapter= new BandDatabaseAdapter(getSherlockActivity());
    bandList  = mySQLiteAdapter.getAllRockBands();

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSherlockActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, android.R.id.text1, bandList));
    }
}
```

you got NullPointerException because you have declared BandDatabaseAdapter but not created its instance. you need create its instance and then call it. in the above code I have created the object first and then called. Hope it helps you.

Comment: this should create the class object, right?  
    `private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;  
  private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;  
  private final Context context;  
    
  public BandDatabaseAdapter(Context c) {  
     sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(c,   BANDDATABASE_NAME, null, BANDDATABASE_VERSION);  
     context = c;  
  }`
(damnit, why doesn't code indenting work in comments?)

Comment: btw, when the helper creates the database it should pop `Log.d(TAG, "Loading bands...");` but it never shows up.

Comment: that's it, database is not created. you are getting SqliteDatabase as null which is throwing NullPointerException. If you add entire code then I can help you something

Comment: Yes! It removes the error and connects the database. But, now the database shows up empty... any tips? :)

Comment: sorted out some things and now it reads the row but gives a fatal error on thread, nullpointer at `return sqLiteDatabase.insert(BANDDATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);`... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

"selection" argument definition :

> A filter declaring which rows to return, formatted as an SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself). Passing null will return all rows for the given table.

Before doing :

```
int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(BAND_NAME);
```

you should check if cursor is null. Same thing for :

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
```

Comment: If you are thinking of checking if there is nothing in the database, it isn't needed since it will always be populated.

Comment: if you don't check if cursor is null before calling the line "int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(BAND_NAME);", and if the cursor is null, you will have NullPointerException as you mentioned it.